# Relating SMS to conversation in Twilio

Tags: javascript, architecture, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm implementing an SMS feature in a Fastify service where users can receive and reply to SMS messages. Each message is linked to a conversation in my database using a conversationId.

When sending out an SMS, I want to attach this conversationId so that when a user replies to the SMS, I can automatically relate their response to the correct conversation using the given conversationId.

Is there a way to embed or associate the conversationId with each outgoing SMS, so it's available when parsing the reply? If not, what would be the work around to this or the correct approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to send a message to a specific conversation?

This could be done with the following code snippet:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.conversations.v1.conversations('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                       .messages
                       .create({author: 'System', body: 'Ahoy there!'})
                       .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

[Docs link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource)